# Isolate all machines in green except one (ipfire)

Tags: networking, firewall

I have a green network: `10.10.10.0/24` in ipfire.

I would like to isolate all machines except one (only within green), i.e. I would like that `10.10.10.2` and `10.10.10.3` cannot communicate with each other, but both can communicate and receive packets from `10.10.10.10`.

how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IPFire is a layer 3 (IP) firewall. What you are looking for is layer 2 filtering, since the traffic from 10.10.10.2 and 10.10.10.3 would never go via the router, thus it wouldn't be blocked by the firewall.

You're going to need an layer 2 forwarding device (switch) that has [private vlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN) or layer 2 filtering functionality.